# INSERT INTO SQL Variable with Whitspaces

Tags: php, mysql

Ok I am pulling my hair out over this, There is no help on google at all for this,

```
if (isset ($_GET['comment']))

    $commentEntered = $_GET['comment'];

else

    $commentEntered = "refuse";
```

Above I get the variable Then I pass it to the database with the code below, Yes I know its in danger of injection.

```
$sql = "insert into $DB_Table (comment) values('$commentEntered');";

$res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close($con);

if ($res) {

    echo "success";

}else{

    echo "faild";
}
```

So When I enter a sentence into a text box it passes it to this php file. The GET method gets the comment entered and stores it in $commentEntered

Now when I enter one word into the text box the comment is stored no problem. But when I enter multiple words separated by a space it wil not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please define "will not work".  What happens?

Comment: no comment is stored in the database

Comment: Have you checked the contents of the parameter, e.g. via `var_dump($_GET['comment']);` ?

Comment: What does `print_r($sql)` give you?

Comment: Im accessing this through an objective C program on the iPhone, which makes it difficult to get any type of error message from it, When I print out $commentEntered it will return it ONLY if there is no Whitespace

Comment: Also, why are you not using prepared statements (PDO)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out whats happening before it hits the query.

```
var_dump($commentEntered)
```

My bet is the URL contains a space and not %20, thus $commentEntered is everything before the first occurrence of a space. Find out by debugging. The only way to fix this is to escape the characters before it hits the script.

Comment: As I said, Im accessing this through an objective C program on the iPhone, this makes it difficult to get any type of error message from it, When I print out $commentEntered it will return it ONLY if there is no Whitespace. You are right in saying that it reads everything before the whitespace although I cannot think why

Comment: Characters need to be escaped, a space means it the end of a URL, you need to escape characters to make it URL friendly before it hits the script. For example...

http://myscript.com/index.php?q=PASS ME NOW
index.php only recognizes PASS
http://myscript.com/index.php?q=PASS%20ME%20NOW
index.php recognizes the whole thing

Comment: a VarDump of $commentEntered returns string(0) "" when i enter no text, when i enter "OK" it returns string(2) "OK", and when I enter "Thats ok" it returns nothing?

Comment: Also test this in the browser, from the App's end you know whats going in right? Copy and paste an expected result to the browser in URL form and see whats happening. You're not limited to the iPhone only.

Comment: Simple, your data isn't getting pushed to the script. Check whats happening before the iPhone App accesses the URL. This is not a MySQL problem. Also debug from the iPhone app, NSLog your URL if possible to see what the exact URL string its sending.

Comment: You got it on the dot :) Big thumbs up mate, I just used a replace string value in the Xcode to replace the whitespace with %20 and it passed the whole comment